# Installing SimpleCV for planet water change calcularion

Tags: anaconda, planet

I'm trying to instal SimpleCV using - pip install https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV (install using this fork to avoid an error in Step 8).

Also already have installed NumPY and OpenCV.

The tutorial that I have tried is the water level change from Planet (sorry I don't have the reputation to post more than 2 links :S).

But I received this error msg

[image: ![enter image description here]

Can someone help me please how to repair this problem?

I already try to download the .zip from the GitHub repository and installed, but the SimpleCV library still has the error with the step of the .findBlobsFromWatershed.

Comment: Please provide all error messages as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command from command line (windows).

```
python -m pip install simplecv
```